# What's wrong with my google analytics tracking event in ajax form?

Tags: ajax, google-analytics

I try to track a ajax form on my website with google analytics. 
But it doesn't work any idea?

In my head section I have :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-11111111-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

In my js file ()

```
$('form :submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var retourtest = testform();
        if(retourtest==true) {

            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-11111111-1']); // your ID/profile
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();

            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'spada', 'contactus']);
```

Also I attach a view of my google analytics config
http://spadatest.be/stack/2014-02-22.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI I also try without this in my js file :
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-11111111-1']); // your ID/profile
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();

Comment: Can you create a pastebin of your site code or share the site? On

Comment: The site is http://www.spada.be/ I replace the trackEvent by _gaq.push(["_trackPageview","/merci.html"]) and It work but is not my initial need
Here the no mimified js http://www.spada.be/js/js.js

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/merci.html']);` in the `request.done` call.

```
$('form :submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var retourtest = testform();
    if(retourtest==true) {          
        $('#validateoutput').show();
        // $('#validateoutput').html('Your message has been sent!');
        $('#validateoutput').removeClass('ko').addClass('ok');
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "sendcontactform.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { sendvar : $('#submitinput').val(),name: $('#nameinput').val(),email: $('#emailinput').val() , phone: $('#phoneinput').val(), comment: $('#commentinput').val() },
            dataType: "html"
        });
        request.done(function( msg ) {
            console.log('msg='+msg);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/merci.html']);
            $( "#validateoutput" ).html( msg );
            $('#nameinput').val('');
            $('#emailinput').val('');
            $('#phoneinput').val('');
            $('#commentinput').val('');
        });
        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: _trackPageview is working. It's _trackEvent that don't work =>_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'spada', 'contactus']);

Answer (score 0):

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'spada', 'contactus']); ?
```

try with:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'spada', 'contactus', 'label']);
```

Replace **label** with another word...

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include an explanation of what the code does, and why it is a better solution than the other answers.